# How to make the column widths of one table always match the corresponding column widths of another table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm asking for is pretty odd, but basically let's say I have two tables:

```html
<table id="table-1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

None of the columns in both of these tables have a set width. The widths depend on what the contents of the cells are. Right now the tables have the same content, so all the columns are the same width. However, let's change one of the cells in table-1.

```html
    <table id="table-1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>This cell is different.</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="table-2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now one of the cells has more content, and as a result column 2 of table-1 will widen. What I want is for column 2 of table-2 to widen as well, no matter what the current contents of its cells are. Basically any dynamic change in the column widths of table-1 I want to match in table-2 via Javascript and/or CSS no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, yeah that's tricky and you want to avoid going down the path of measuring cell widths and trying to manage the widths manually. I would suggest that you use `table-layout: fixed; width: 100%`. This makes it so that all of the table columns will have the same width. The table will be responsive to it's container, so if both tables are in the same container, they should have the same column widths. Here's an example showing this:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
table tr th {
  text-align: left;
}
.small-container {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>This cell is different.</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="table-2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <hr/>
    <h5>Small Container example</h5>
    <div class="small-container">
    <table id="table-1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>This cell is different.</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="table-2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't want the every column to be the same width. I want the columns of the first table to be as wide as its longest cell and the second table to have matching widths to the first.

Comment: Yes I understand, I was showing you an alternative to your problem. To achieve what you want, you'll need to use JS to measure each cell and update both tables to the same width. That's not going to be an easy task.